# How to register events posted from Firebird with parameters in Delphi

Tags: delphi, events, firebird

I have an event posted from firebird database in a trigger after a new record is inserted like this: post_event 'SPOOL' + new.username;
I want to register this event with SIBfibEventAlerter (FIBPlus) in a Delphi application and run a procedure. Problem is that event name depends on user name added the record.

Comment: Maybe you could read the usernames from the user table (if `new.username` is actually a field and not some FB system value) and create the eventalerters components dynamically, one per user name.

Comment: @mjn: You should post that as an answer to get the credit. I think there's no other way to really do this using "parameters"..

Answer (score 3):

You could read the usernames from the user table (if `new.username` is actually a field and not some FB system value) and create the eventalerters components dynamically, one per user name.

Comment: The problem is, the OP posts the event from an after-insert trigger, so the new record is not visible to outside transactions yet (assuming default snapshot isolation).

Comment: @TOndrej correct if it is the after insert trigger for the user table. If it is for example an insert into an order table, which has the username field, it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since events don't really support parameters, one way would be to add extra fields to table, which contain auto incremental id (or timestamp) and the data you need as a parameter.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Use a single parameterless event, in the alerter query the table for new records, use specific information from returned results. If needed, update the records to prevent from processing again on next event.